# Using Javascript On Page - Header and Footer Now Missing

Tags: php, functions, javascript, headers, footer

We have a custom product filter to display vehicles on a /products page.

The filter uses Javascript and the JS code is place directly on the /products page content editor.
The JS code is also placed on the page.php template that was created exclusively for the /products page.

We also have a function that placed in the functions.php file to display the custom filter on the /products page.

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
add_rewrite_rule('products/(.*)', 'index.php?page_id=104937/$matches[1]', 
'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

The product page works, the filter works, but the header and footer no longer show up on the /products page. I have checked the page templates that are used for the /products page, and they do call the header and footer.

Any ideas why the header and footer no longer show up and is there a way to "force" them to show up?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but that `/$matches[1]` in the rewrite rule's *query* doesn't seem valid. And as with the actual question, it could be anything, but to start with, check the page source/HTML - are there any PHP errors? Check also the browser console and PHP logs.

Comment: We found that the script was overriding the page template. Would be nice to be able to somehow force the header and footer to be visible.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "overriding the page template"? What does the script override? What errors you see in the HTML/console/logs?

Comment: I apologize for not being more clear on this. The script that is used to display the vehicles on the product page is somehow overriding the entire page. So that is making the header and footer not visible...if that makes sense. I have been looking for solutions to see if it is possible to somehow force the header and footer to be visible. This issue is more advanced than my current skillset. I will get more familiar with how to properly use the html/console logs and add comments.

Comment: If you use Chrome, see [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools). And if it's a JS issue, you should probably post a question on Stack Overflow, and either link to the page in question or post a fiddle where people can reproduce the issue (and fix it..).